# I want to know why this don't work the same(function definition outside-main and if inside-main function)

Tags: c, sorting, if-statement, program-entry-point, self

```
#include <stdio.h>

int generator(int n) {
    int ten[6]; // array that saves digit number
    int result = n; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        ten[i] = n % 10; //saving digit number
        n = n / 10;
        result += ten[i];
    }
    return result;
 }
void sort(int x, int y) { //the problem function. it didn't work
if (x > y) {
    int temp;
    temp = y;
    y = x;
    x = temp;
}


int main(void) {
    int number[10000];
    int selfNumber[10000];
    int result[10000];


    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        number[i] = generator(i+1); //generator function
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", number[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (number[i] > number[i + 1]) { //it worked.
            int temp;
            temp = number[i + 1];
            number[i+1] = number[i];
            number[i]=temp;
        }
        sort(number[i], number[i + 1]);
     }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", number[i]);
    }
    return 0;
```

I defined the *void function* sort to sort the numbers in size. But it didn't work.
So, I used *if* inside of main function to sort the numbers in size.
I don't know why it does work it different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sort` function takes parameters by value (pass-by-value), i.e. it use copy of the numbers you passed to it. `sort` exchange that copies successfully, but it's not the behaviour you expect.

Use pointers (or references in C++) when you want pass-by-reference semantics:

```c
void sort(int* x, int* y) {
  if (*x > *y) {
    int temp = *y;
    *y = *x;
    *x = temp;
  }
}
```

Read more about pointers [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/pointer).

Comment: oh.... I forgot about that... Thanks for reminding me about pass-by-references

Answer (score 0):

You are passing x & y by value to the `sort` function, so when you return any changes are lost. You might want to pass pointers instead:

```
void sort(int *x, int *y) {
    if (*x > *y) {
        int temp;
        temp = *y;
        *y = *x;
        *x = temp;
    }
}
```

This will cause the original values to be changed, not just the local copies.